# How can I use intellij as a simple tree browser+editor

Tags: intellij-idea

When I start intellij, it appears to impose a project centric view on me, like this:

[image: project centric view]

How can I get IntelliJ to give me something more similar to that provided by eclipse's "remote system explorer" or NERDTree?  I'd like to do this without external plugins, because some of them have crashed my IDE before.

Comment: Isn't your project missing a module?

Comment: i actually dont have any modules.  I have a large folder of source code with many different files in it.  I dont want to force it into an intellij project.

Comment: You must have a module, the same way you must have a project in Eclipse.